# Google AIplatform: how to submit a job?

Tags: python, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to build a custom container on Google AI platform.

From the [document](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-containers#submit_your_training_job), I can submit a job with command line.

I would like to submit a job with http request. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can submit jobs via http request. I'd recommend using one of the [google api client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) to help simplify making the request.